# I want to use 5 stepper motors with my Raspberry pi 4 8 gig

Tags: pi-4

I want to use 5 stepper motors with my raspberry pi but I am kind of new to this and could only make one work till now using the tutorials found on the web and this is where I figured out all the tutorials use pin 20 and 21 for direction and stepping which is bugging me as my raspberry pi has 40 gpio pins and I know what is gnd, 3v3 and other pins mean but if I could use all the other gpio pins to make the motors spin.

The purpose for using the stepper motor is to create a multistage motion in my cnc.

Thank you

Comment: Ah, you don't need to use pin 20 and 21 all the time.  You can use other GPIO pins, two each for each another motor. In case you run out of pins, you can use 8-pin, or 16-pin GPIO expanders. You can search AdaFruit of SparkFun for newbie friendly tutorials on say, MCP23008 etc. Let me @tlfong01 know if you have difficulty in reading the tutorials.

Comment: what is preventing you from experimenting and trying other pins?

Comment: Voltage spikes I guess, probably ending up damaging gpio pins

Comment: Voltage spikes can damage pins 20&21 as easily as any others.

Comment: Already had that damaged, all I had to do is plug out the A4988 stepper driver to replace it with a new one, now both the new stepper driver and the GPIO pin 21 is not working